# Ruby - Sorting of nested array of arrays with integers as strings

Tags: ruby, sorting

I am attempting to perform a sort of the array of arrays below. I am successfully able to perform the actual sort operation using `sort_by` but I cannot update the original array.

Instead, I am resorting to pushing each modified hash to a new array (`array`) and then trying to re-integrate/merge it with the original one which I don't think is the right approach for something as simple as sorting string integers...  How do I simply sort the below data format? **Creating a new object is perfectly acceptable**; this does not require an in-place sort operation but either approach is acceptable.

**Expected Outcome**

My goal is to simply sort ascending the chapter numbers (strings) which are the keys in my hashes.  So, for example, Matthew is already in order however Acts should list `6` first, followed by `9`. Romans should list `2` first, followed by `15`, etc.   Most importantly, the order of books (Matthew, Acts, Romans, and Revelation) must remain in tact.

**Here's what I've tried:**

```
array = Array.new

data.each do |x|
  array << Hash[x.last.sort_by {|k,v| k.to_i }]
end

# 'array' now contains accurate data that has been sorted but it more difficult to re-merge it than to simply sort the original data
```

**Here's my data:**

```
data = [["Matthew",
  {"4"=>[{:book=>"Matthew", :verse=>"18-20", :section=>"new_testament"}],
   "22"=>[{:book=>"Matthew", :verse=>"37-38", :section=>"new_testament"}]}],
 ["Acts",
  {"9"=>[{:book=>"Acts", :verse=>"8", :section=>"new_testament"}],
   "6"=>[{:book=>"Acts", :verse=>"27-28", :section=>"new_testament"}]}],
 ["Romans",
  {"15"=>[{:book=>"Romans", :verse=>"13A", :section=>"new_testament"}],
   "2"=>[{:book=>"Romans", :verse=>"4", :section=>"new_testament"}]}],
 ["Revelation",
  {"7"=>[{:book=>"Revelation", :verse=>"9-10", :section=>"new_testament"}],
   "2"=>[{:book=>"Revelation", :verse=>"2-5B", :section=>"new_testament"}],
   "1"=>[{:book=>"Revelation", :verse=>"9-10", :section=>"new_testament"}]}]]
```

Comment: Is ordering of 5A vs. 5B important? Don't forget `[ ]` is more succinct than `Array.new` except when you need to supply arguments to the `new` method.

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks for the reminder.  Ordering 5A before 5B makes the most sense considering the purpose of my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were just about there... just include the book name in your output.

```
new_data = []

data.each do |x|
  new_data << [ x[0], Hash[x[1].sort_by{|k,_| k.to_i }] ]
end
```

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for such a quick reply.  The outcome of the above command has slightly different structure to the original array.   The original is `[["Matthew",{"4"=>[{:book=>"Matthew",......` and the output of your answer produces `[["Matthew",[["4",[{:book=>"Matthew",......`.  For this one, I need to preserve the order of the original data identically.   Thank you again...

Comment: Yes, I forgot to include the `Hash[..]` encapsulation.  I edited my answer but you probably took it as first posted.

Comment: Thanks Steve--it works perfectly!   I understand it perfectly, but can't seem to understand why I couldn't see it from the beginning... it was so easy, AGAIN.   I'm getting a little disheartened cause I continue to run into problems that take 4 hours of banging my head before asking for help and people solve them in 5 minutes.   Nonetheless, thank you so much!

Comment: Steve, not entirely relevant to the original question, but if you have a moment, I'd also like to solve this.   Let's pretend there are 3 verses in the same chapter, how would you go about sorting the `:verse` values in the same manner?   Meaning, let's pretend that Romans Chapter 15 has 3 verses (verse 12, verse 4, and verse 8).  If I want them to appear as verse 4, verse 8, and verse 12 in that order, how would you approach it?  Thank you again and don't feel the need to answer if it's a pain.

Comment: `sort_by{|k, d| [k to_i, d[:verse].to_i, d[:verse]]}` sort by chapter then verse numeric then 13 before 13A

Comment: The nice thing about banging your head for 4 hours is that you remember for next time :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126279/discussion-between-kurt-w-and-steveturczyn).

Comment: Hi sorry Kurt invite to chat came at 1 am my time so was tucked away!